# LinkedIn API get other user's information

Tags: php, api, rest, linkedin-api, social-networking

I'm developing an application that uses the LinkedIn API (and other social networks') to retrieve the messages you receive in yout timeline and get other user's information.

I know that I can't get that information over a user since the last API update thay made, but I'd like to know if that's possible from a company page. I can get the updates I've made on the page and my user profile but what I want is to get the user's profile from a person that makes a like in one of my publications (to put and example).

Is that possible like with the Facebook API and Twitter API or I can only access to information from the user that is authenticated in the application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, only You can get that information with authenticated users in the application.
As for LinkedIn, I don't know if you know that from May 12 (if I remember correctly) LinkedIn API is changed.
[Changes in Linkedin API](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes)